# How to translate ViewBox's coordinates to specific SVG element's center in Javascript (without libraries)

Tags: javascript, svg, viewbox

I have a global draggable SVG and element on it. even SVG viewBox show me another dragged position, when I click to button viewBox's center should set to center of element.

```
center = {x: element.height/2, y: element.width/2}


         var center = translateResultToCentroid();
         elements.forEach(function(element) {
          element.setAttribute(
            'viewBox',
            (center.x) +
              ' ' +
            (center.y) +
              ' ' +
            viewboxHeight +
              ' ' +
            viewboxWidth
          );
        });
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Comment: @KoshVery like now?

Comment: Try `element.setAttributeNS(null, "viewBox", whatever);`

Comment: You example code doesn't make much sense. If my suspicion is right, the first line should really be part of the forEach callback function, or what is `element` in that expression? Then, you find the center of an (`<svg>`?) element in coordinates of its parent element and set the upper left corner of its `viewBox`, in the coordinate system of its content, to that center. What should that achieve? - Finally, `viewboxWidth` and `viewboxHeight` are never defined and seem to be mentioned in the wrong order. Please post code that is executable.